# Unplated icon for MSIX-packed Win32-application doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, taskbar, windows-store

I am trying to generate a MSIX-installer for a Win32-OpenGL-application, which is supposed to be deployed in Microsoft Store. Therefore, I have first built the .exe-file in Visual Studio and packed it with MSIX Packaging Tool to a .msix-installer. After that, I edited the .msix-package and added the required images (Square44x44Logo.png, Square71x71Logo.png,...). Unfortunately, I found out that the icon in the task bar was plated. I tried to add another image (`Square44x44Logo.targetsize-44_altform-unplated.png`) to the .msix-package by editing it again with the MSIX Packaging Tool, but the task bar icon remained plated. How can I change my task bar icon to unplated?

Answer (score 1):

[Unplated assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#unplated-assets)

> By default, Windows uses a target-based asset on top of a colored
>   backplate by default. If you want, you can provide a target-based
>   unplated asset. "Unplated" means the asset will be displayed on a
>   **transparent** background. Keep in mind that these assets will appear
>   over a variety of background colors.

[Unplated assets and themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#unplated-assets-and-themes)

> The user's selected theme determines the color of the taskbar. If the
>   unplated asset isn't specifically qualified for the current theme, the
>   system checks the asset for contrast. If it has enough contrast with
>   taskbar, the system uses it. Otherwise, the system looks for a
>   high-contrast version of the asset. If it can't find one, the system
>   draws the plated form of the asset instead.

Follow the steps below to solve this problem:

- Obtain the correct 44x44 images and then copy them into the folder
  that contains your images (i.e., Assets).
- For each 44x44 image, create a copy in the same folder and append
  .targetsize-44_altform-unplated to the file name. You should have two
  copies of each icon, each named in a specific way. For example, after
  completing the process, your assets folder might contain
  MYAPP_44x44.png and MYAPP_44x44.targetsize-44_altform-unplated.png.
- In the manifest file, **set the BackgroundColor for every icon you are
  making transparent**.
- Continue to the next subsection to generate a new Package Resource
  Index file.

For more details, refer: [Add Target-based unplated assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion#optional-add-target-based-unplated-assets)

Here is a similar case for your reference.

- [unplated taskbar icons in Desktop Bridge apps](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/dc505f68-d120-43e3-a9e1-d7c77746d588/uwpdesktop-bridgeunplated-taskbar-icons-in-desktop-bridge-apps?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Answers that depend on links are not helpful... most links are now outdated

Comment: @BrunoGuardia  Answer requires more text to explain to prevent the hyperlink from becoming invalid. I also attached some excerpts from each link below to supplement the answer, but OP did not reply to me, so I am not sure if the answer is useful to him.